# saving data in session an email after certain time

Tags: php, session

I am planning to make a three step contact form, when user complete the first step data is saved in session and go in second step and then third all data will me bailed to me but if somewhere in between user leave I will be mailed what ever is entered?

How do i do that?

Comment: If you want data to persist longer than sessions, then don't store the data in the session. Put the submissions from the previous steps of the form in hidden inputs of the following steps, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Store values in database with `session_id`.

if user completes the steps you can remove them after a succeeded mail process.

But if user leaves your form before complete the form, you will have the values stored anyway. Set a cron job to check these values, email to yourself and remove.